# Not able to access the animate.css's animation keyframe names from scss file

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, css-modules, animate.css

I'm trying to use animate.css with React/Next.js. I can create animations using animate.css's inline class names, but I want to call animate.css's keyframe animations from my `scss` file. I was following a youtube guide and he was able to do it. The only difference is that I'm using Next.js.

As a reference:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESHaail1eGc&t=4379s&ab_channel=CodewithSloba

He imports the `animate.css` file at 3:55 and and is able to use animate.css's `bounceIn` animation at 38:31.

**Example:**

In my `styles/globals.scss` file, I added animate.css

```
@import 'animate.css'
```

In my `AnimateLetters.tsx` file, at the top I import the scss module,

```
import styles from '../../styles/AnimatedLetters.module.scss'
```

In the same file and inside the React component,

This works for me:

```
<span className='animate__animated animated__bounceIn'> H </span>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<span className={styles.animateText}> H </span>
```

In my `AnimatedLetters.module.scss`, I have

```
.animateText {
  display: inline-block;
  animation-name: bounceIn;
  animation-duration: 2s
}
```

A hacky way of getting by this is finding the keyframe inside the `node_modules/animate.css/animate.css` file and then copying it into my scss file, like below:

```
@keyframes bounceIn {
  from,
  20%,
  40%,
  60%,
  80%,
  to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
    transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
    transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.97, 0.97, 0.97);
    transform: scale3d(0.97, 0.97, 0.97);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

I would prefer not to have to do this. Also, if I do resort to this, would it be best just to uninstall animate.css and just copy the keyframes I'm using into my `global.scss`?

Comment: Which file is the `.animateText` styling declared in? How are you importing that Sass file in your JavaScript file? If you're using a Sass module file, then you'll have to import it like `import styles from '<path-to>/animate-text.module.scss'`, then use the class as `styles.animateText`.

Comment: @juliomalves Yes, you're right. Sorry, in my haste, my example was actually incorrect. I have a _AnimatedLetters.tsx_ file where my React component has a tag `<span className={styles.textAnimate}> H </span>`. At the top, I have `import styles from '../../styles/AnimatedLetters.module.scss'`. In my AnimatedLetters.module.scss file, I have a `.textAnimate` selector with `animation: bounceIn`. Without me pasting the actual animate.css keyframe code for bounceIn into the scss file, the animation doesn't work. There seems to be some disconnect between my scss file and animate.css that I'm missing.

Comment: I updated my original post to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `bounceIn` animation is declared globally (i.e. imported from `animate.css` in your `globals.scss`), you have to use the `:global` selector when using it in your Sass Modules file. Otherwise, Sass Modules assumes `bounceIn` is locally scoped and will hash the animation name.

```css
.animateText :global {
    display: inline-block;
    animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-duration: 2s
}

/* or */

.animateText {
    display: inline-block;
    animation-duration: 2s
    &:global {
        animation-name: bounceIn;
    }
}
```

By default, CSS Modules assumes everything is locally scoped. If you want to access anything that's globally scoped you have to use `:global`.

Comment: Appreciate your help! As a follow-up, when I try to use a hover pseudo-class within .animateText, I get an error. 

`Error: Missing whitespace after :global
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)`


**Example**

`.animateText :global {
  display: inline-block;
  animation-name: bounceIn;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  &:hover {
    color: blue;
  }
}`
If I removed the hover child and created a separate selector for hover as below, it works as expected
`.animateText:hover {
  color: blue;
}`
Is this just how it is when using :global?

Comment: That's one way to get around it, but you could also just scope `animation-name: bounceIn;` globally by doing `&:global { animation-name: bounceIn; }`. You'd then be free to use `&:hover { color: blue; }`. I've updated my answer to provide an alternate syntax.